# PHP fgetcsv - detecting too many records

Tags: php, csv

I have the following csv file:

```
"Id","Title","Body","Tags"
"101","this title","
\""&gt;.&lt;/&gt;"";
","c# asp.net excel table"
```

which I want to convert into an array as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Id
            [1] => Title
            [2] => Body
            [3] => Tags
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 101
            [1] => this title
            [2] => \""&gt;.&lt;/&gt;"";
            [3] => c# asp.net excel table
        )
)
```

My code is:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);

    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        $data[$c] = strip_tags($data[$c]);
    }

    $result[$row] = $data;
    $row++;
}
fclose($handle);
return $result;
```

My problem is I am getting the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Id
            [1] => Title
            [2] => Body
            [3] => Tags
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 101
            [1] => this title
            [2] => 
\">.</>"";
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ,c# asp.net excel table"
        )

)
```

In general, how do I avoid detecting too many recors when there is potentially code inside the fields (it's a StackOverflow data dump so some text fields have all kinds of programming code).

Answer (score 1):

This string is not correctly escaped:

```
"
\""&gt;.&lt;/&gt;"";
"
```

All quote chars must have backslashes before them (or other escape char that you've passed into appropriate param.
And you should't pass 0 and comma to fgetcsv, they are already default: http://php.net/fgetcsv

Comment: So the solution would be to search for all quote characters, and add the backslash except when it matches my proper line delimiter (",") ?

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the file using [CSVed](http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/) to make sure that it was properly formatted as CSV.

If the CSV is broken, then you can do some quick fix to the parsed result. For example:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);

    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        $data[$c] = strip_tags($data[$c]);
    }

    if (count($data) == 3) {
        $data[1][2] .= $data[2].[0];
        unset($data[2]);
    }

    $result[$row] = $data;
    $row++;
}
fclose($handle);
return $result;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. CSVed also has problem parsing the data, and detected lots of errors. I am no sure what to do next...

Comment: Try fixing the parsed result. It would be case by case.