# Parsing Stackoverflow csv data in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I want to convert Stackoverflow csv data (from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/facebook-recruiting-iii-keyword-extraction/data)) into a PHP array.

The csv is formatted as follows:

```
Id,Title,Body,Tags
```

The problem I am facing is that my script finds too many rows (I posted more details in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117362/php-fgetcsv-detecting-too-many-records/19118542#comment28270412_19118542)); it might be due to unescaped quotes in the `Body` field.

Do I really have to look for unescaped quotes and add a backslah except for those that really match the data delimitation format "," ?

Or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

Try this csv parser: https://code.google.com/p/php-csv-parser/ or http://www.creativedev.in/2012/01/to-parse-csv-data-in-php/ it should be more memory efficient

Answer (score 1):

If the CSV file is correctly generated and doesn't contain any errors a solution with `fgetcsv` should be fine.

Other CSV readers will likely run into the same problem.

Comment: I did try with fgetcsv but had some problems; refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117362/php-fgetcsv-detecting-too-many-records/19118542

Comment: I know, I checked that, and someone answered saying that the source CSV is bad.